# $L^1$ convergence of Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have the following functions:
\begin{equation}
S_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
S(x) = \int_x^{x+1}f(y)dy.
\end{equation}
I would like to show that $S_n\to S$ in $L^1$, provided that $f\in L^1$. I mean, this intuitively makes sense: $S_n$ is the the "Riemann sum" for the integral (I know, very imprecise) $\int_x^{x+1}f(y)dy$ as $n\to\infty$.

I have two obstacles: First showing that $S_n\to S$ point-wise (is it necessary? It is for the proof I have in my mind) as $n\to\infty$, and then showing that I can interchange the limit in the integral
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{x+1}\left|f(y)-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right|dydx.
\end{equation}

Any help would be very helpful!

Comment: $S_n\to S$ pointwise is not going to happen, your $S_n(x)$ is not even defined pointwise. One can change $f(x)$ at countably many points and still have the same $f\in L^1$. If $f=0$ at rational points and $1$ at irrationals, for example, then so is $S_n$, but not $S$. The best you can hope for is almost everywhere.

Comment: I meant a.e. point-wise convergence.

Comment: @user134070 what don't you like about zhw's answer?

Comment: This is an old qualifying exam problem from analysis, which does not cover topics on linear operators. I am looking for a solution that only involves rudimentary analysis theorems, such as DCT.

Comment: @user134070 btw you should tag me in your replies so that I can see that you replied (I only saw now by chance). And I don't think zhw's solution uses anything nontrivial. He is just phrasing things in terms of bounded linear operators. You should take some time to think about what he's saying. it's all elementary, trust me

Comment: The methods I propose in my hint are mostly more elementary than the DCT. There is one result that might go a little bit beyond that, but is still well within the bounds of a bieginning course in measure theory: Let $f\in L^1$ and $\epsilon >0.$ Then there exists a continuous $g$ with compact support such that $\|f-g\|_1<\epsilon.$ Are you familiar with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: 1. Show that the maps $f\to S_n(f,x), f\to S(f,x)$ are bounded linear operators from $L^1$ to $L^1,$ all of whose norms are $\le 1.$ 2. Show the desired result holds for a dense subspace of $L^1.$ 3. Conclude that the desired result holds for $L^1.$

---

I will expand on my hint above. This will be part sketch and part solution.

First, show the result holds if $f$ is continuous with compact support. You're basically back in Riemann integral territory here. Uniform continuity is the key.

Second, the result I mentioned in a comment: Let $f\in L^1$ and $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists a continuous $g$ with compact support such that $\|f-g\|_1<\epsilon.$

On to linearity: If $f,g\in L^1$ and $a,b\in \mathbb R,$ then

$$S_n(af+bg) = aS_n(f)+bS_n(g),\,\, S(af+bg) = aS(f)+bS(g).$$

This is easy to verify.

$L^1$ boundedness: Let $f\in L^1.$ Then

$$\int_{\mathbb R}|S_n(f)(x)|\,dx = \int_{\mathbb R}\left |  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right|\,dx \le \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left |f\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right|\,dx $$ $$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{\mathbb R}\left |f\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right|\, dx = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{\mathbb R}\left |f\left(x\right)\right|\, dx = \int_{\mathbb R}\left |f\left(x\right)\right|\, dx.$$

The translation invariance of Lebesgue measure was used in the second-to-last equality.

As for $S(f),$ note

$$\int_{\mathbb R} |S(f)(x)|\,dx = \int_{\mathbb R} |\int_x^{x+1}f(t)\,dt|\,dx \le \int_{\mathbb R} \int_x^{x+1}|f(t)|\,dt\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R} |f(t)|\,dt.$$

Fubini was used in the last equality. I'll leave it to you, for now, to verify that we have the proper papers to use it. (Ask if you have questions.)

Finally we can prove the desired result. Let $f\in L^1.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose $g$ continuous with compact support such that $\|f-g\|_1<\epsilon.$ Then from the work above, we have

$$\|S_n(f)-S(f)\|_1 \le \|S_n(f)-S_n(g)\|_1  + \|S_n(g)-S(g)\|_1 + \|S(g)-S(f)\|_1$$ $$ \le \|f-g\|_1 + \|S_n(g)-S(g)\|_1 + \|g-f\|_1< 2\epsilon + \|S_n(g)-S(g)\|_1.$$

It follows that

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \|S_n(f)-S(f)\|_1 \le 2\epsilon + \lim_{n\to \infty}\|S_n(g)-S(g)\|_1 = 2\epsilon.$$

Because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, the $\limsup$ on the left is $0,$ and we are done.

Comment: I've expanded on my hint. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! It does help greatly.

Comment: You're welcome. Are you studying for qualifying exams?

Comment: Yes I am, sadly.

Comment: Why the "sadly'? Is it because you have to study through the winter break?